# SQL query joining two table with a concerned condition check for android room with embedded and relation with condition check

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I have two main tables 'cars' and 'colors'.

- In cars the columns are carId , isPurchase , carName
- In colors the columns are colorId , colorName

I need to get the SQL query which return all cars and colors for the cars only for which isPurchase is true both in a SINGLE QUERY

```
@Entity
class Cars{
   @ PrimaryKey
     val carId,
     val carName,
     val isPurchased
}
@Entity
class Colors{
  @ PrimaryKey
     val colorId,
     val colorName,

}

@Entity(tableName = "car_color_join",
    primaryKeys = arrayOf("colorId","carId"),
    foreignKeys = arrayOf(
            ForeignKey(entity = Color::class,
                    parentColumns = arrayOf("carId"),
                    childColumns = arrayOf("colorId"),
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
            ForeignKey(entity = Car::class,
                    parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                    childColumns = arrayOf("platformId"),
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    ))

 data class CarColorJoin(
    val packId:Int,
    val platformId:Int  )
```

I created a class for embedding getting the full details of cars and colors in one object

```
class CarColor{

@Embedded
lateinit var cars : Car


@Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "carID", entity = CarColorJoin::class)
lateinit var carColors: List<JoinedCarColors>
}

class JoinedCarColors{

@Embedded
lateinit var carColorJoin: carColorJoin

@Relation(parentColumn = "colorId", entityColumn = "id", entity = Colors::class)
lateinit var colors: List<Colors>     
}
```

I need to get the query which returns all cars and only the colors for the cars that has isPurchased true in single query.

Also can I add condition check inside that relation object .

Comment: Your Helps are Appreciated!!!!

Comment: Try to fix some mismatches in your classes/fields' names. It could help to somebody who will try to help you. E.g. in one piece of your post there is a `Car` class, in another - `Cars`, the same with `Color` and `Colors`.  Fields of `CarColorJoin` doesn't match neither to primary nor to foreign keys and so on.